# not able to get the correct row count for parent grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I am not able to get  child grid data like as getting parent grid data and getting wrong number of rows from parent grid ... I am  using kendo ui Grid hierarchy grid format , I am using below code for that purpose

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnMove').click(function () {

        var count = $('#Gridparent').data('kendoGrid').tbody[0].rows.length;

        alert(count); // here I am getting 5 number but actually i hav 4 rows 

        var sourcegrid = $('#GridParent').data('kendoGrid');  
        alert(' first button clicked');  // here is  ok    

        var destinationgrid = $('#grid_#=CostPage#').data('kendoGrid');
        alert('second button clicked'); // not getting this alert
```

and this is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.CostPageSearch>()
        .Name("Gridparent")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Width(30);
            columns.Bound(e => e.CostPage).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Description).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.VendorName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeDirect).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeWarehouse).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.VendorName).Width(100);    
        })
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:480px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(6)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "CostPageDisplay"))
        )
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
)
    <script id="client-template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
         @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.ItemsDescriptionModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=CostPage#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Width(30);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemId).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemDescription).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.BrandCode).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.PackSize).Width(100);
            })
           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
               .Ajax()
               .PageSize(5)
               .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "CostPageDisplay" , new { employeeID = "#=CostPage#" }))
           )
           .ToClientTemplate()
   )
    </script>
<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        //alert('1');
    }
</script>
```

I am not able to see the alert `second button clicked` and not able to get the correct  row  count as well for the below code

```
            var count = $('#Gridparent').data('kendoGrid').tbody[0].rows.length;
```

would any one pls help on this .. many thanks....

Comment: your selector `$('#grid_#=CostPage#')` won't be getting a valid object so you cannot do a `.data` on the end

Comment: @Pete yes you are right pete i have changed the code pls see below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with these lines ....I am getting data from first line and and i am getting correct row count from second line...

```
var childGriddata = $('#GridParent').closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid"); 

var actualrowcount = $('#Gridparent').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total();
```